# Null pointer exception at preparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I am designing simple bank application using servlet and jdbc 
so while inserting data into database I am getting null pointer exception at preparedStatement

my code for that is

```
Connection con=null;
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement =null;

     try
     {
     con = DBConnection.createConnection();
     String query = "insert into cst_details(name,surname,aadhar_no,contact_no,address,balance) "
            + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
     preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
     preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
     preparedStatement.setString(2, surname);
     preparedStatement.setString(3, aadhar_no);
     preparedStatement.setString(4, contact_no);
     preparedStatement.setString(5, address);
     preparedStatement.setString(6,initial_bal);
```

Comment: Isn't con null? Did you check connection created successfully?

Comment: Can you post your error stack trace?  It might help if it points out where the null pointer exception is being thrown.

Comment: please, put your error stackTrace

Comment: Verify that your connection is not null and that all parameters have non null values.  And only you can do this.